# WIldcards in MS DOCX Find-Replace

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace

I have long list of emails in docx.  Each email/line.  There are several `xyz[at]example.com` and `xyz[at]xyz.png` type entries.  How to delete entire line/email by searching for `.png` and `[at]example.com`?  Example:

These are results from email extractor which goes to even unwanted pages within the website.

Comment: Could you paste a reasonably long list of examples here please?

Can this problem be solved using `regex`?

Comment: Pasted above. I have in column form, here its coming in text wrap form.

Comment: Regex = [^a-zA-Z0-9-](?<num>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,20}@[A-Za-z0-9_-]{3,20}\.[\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]

Comment: docx is a file format, so it can't do any find/replace. The replacing is done by MS Word

Comment: You should **NEVER EVER post others' e-mail address publicly**, please post non-sensitive data as example.

Comment: how to do replacing in ms word?